# write_csv() not working even after setting directory in RStudio Cloud

Tags: r, rstudio, read.csv

I can't seem to get this csv file to show up regardless of how many variations I use of write_csv, including directory changes. How can I do this (in either RStudio Cloud or the local program)? I did not truly see a duplicate of this problem in other posts, and no error is involved. Any advice as a beginner would be appreciated, thank you.

```
  # read in the raw data
  init_updata <- readxl::read_excel("/cloud/project/secondalgdummy.xlsx")
  
  #--------------------------------------------------
  # PROCESSING
  #--------------------------------------------------
  processed_data <- init_updata %>%
    select_if(~!all(is.na(.))) %>% # remove NA cols
    dplyr::mutate(
      PAIN_SEVERITY = select(., starts_with("PAIN_INTENSITY")) %>% 
        rowMeans(na.rm = TRUE),
      N_BODYMAP_SEGMENTS = dplyr::pull(., BODYMAP_REGIONS_CSV) %>%
        count_segments() %>%
        replace_na(0),
      BODYMAP_REGIONS = dplyr::pull(., BODYMAP_REGIONS_CSV) %>%
        concat_regions(),
      PAIN_DURATION = PAIN_EXP_DURATION_YEARS*12 + PAIN_EXP_DURATION_MONTHS + PAIN_EXP_DURATION_DAYS/30
    ) %>%
    dplyr::select(MRN, all_of(all_vars))
  #--------------------------------------------------
  # MUNGING
  #--------------------------------------------------
  # not imputing data in this project --> remove patients with NA values
munged_data <- processed_data[complete.cases(select(processed_data, all_of(ind_vars))), ]
write_csv(munged_data, "full_munged_data.csv")
```

Comment: Do you get an error or does it appear to work? Is the problem just with the csv? Can you write any other files? Are you sure you have write access?

Comment: Before you run `write_csv(...)` try running `munged_data` to make sure it's what you expect. If it is, run `write_csv(...)` and carefully look for any messages/errors. If it seems to have worked, run `getwd()` to make sure you're writing to the place you think you're writing to.

Comment: @SamR I do not get an error or file at all. Really strange. Yes I have access and other files do not work.

Comment: @313phant So R acts like nothing went wrong. What is the output of `getwd()` right after you attempted to write the csv? And of `list.files(pattern="csv")`?